# Remove space between subplots in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a a large space in between my subplots in plotly. In matplotlib, there is a layout called a tight layout that removes this. Is there any similar layout in plotly? I am plotting in an iPython notebook so there is limited space. See the space in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes there is!  You can use `specs` and `vertical_spacing` or `horizontal_spacing`.  Here is an example for `horizontal_spacing`:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

trace1 = Scatter(
     x=[1, 2, 3],
     y=[4, 5, 6]
)
trace2 = Scatter(
     x=[20, 30, 40],
     y=[50, 60, 70],
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = 1, cols = 2, specs = [[{}, {}]],
                          horizontal_spacing = 0.05)

fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)

py.iplot(fig, filename='make-subplot-horizontal_spacing')
```

[image: here is the plot]

You can find more tutorials on Plotly subplots page: [Plotly subplots tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-x-axes)

Comment: The details of specs aren't clear.  Is there a docs page on it explaining it in more detail?

Comment: Negative.  I'm sure there is something somewhere, but plotly's docs are not easy to find/navigate from what I recall.

Comment: `tools.make_subplots()` is now deprecated. You can obtain the same results with `plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows = rows, cols = cols, horizontal_spacing = 0.05)`