# Place two plotly generated tables adjacent to each other

Tags: python, plotly

I have created two Plotly tables that are of different dimensions and want to place them beside each other. Is there a way to perform this task without the implementation of dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make the tables [subplots of type table](https://plotly.com/python/table-subplots/):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "table"}, {"type": "table"}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(values=["A", "B"]),
        cells=dict(values=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8]]),
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(values=["C", "D", "E"]),
        cells=dict(values=[[3, 6, 9, 12, 15], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]]),
    ),
    row=1,
    col=2,
)
fig.show()
```

[image: tables]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to incorporate the data type ( for instance percentage, float with 2 integers etc.) with the individual tables (In my case the tables do not have the same data format) ?

Comment: Each table works separately and can have its own formatting. This is out of the scope of this question, but you can add a `format` property to the `cells` dictionaries. For example: `cells=dict(values=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8]], format = [None, ",.2f"],)` formats the second column to have two decimal places. Adjust according to your needs. If an answer solves your question problem be sure to upvote and accept.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly....Just one query, is there a way to reduce the gap between the two tables?

Comment: I haven't tested it out, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31528495/9098350) probably works.